# fixing a crack in this pot

Tags: repair

I’m looking to fix this crack so the water doesn’t come out but I’m not sure how I would go about that ? I’m not even sure of the material , it doesn’t seem to be a ceramic but I’m not to sure really .
[image: pot]

Comment: Generally, knowing the material you're fixing is important in figuring out how to fix it. What does it look like w/o all the dirt in it?

Comment: as @crip659 wrote it probably happened due to freezing, in a similar case with a pot looking similar to this one I couldn't fix it- when I took out the dirt it simply fell apart so think twice before you buy any repairstuff.

Answer (score 1):

To just seal, silicone caulk should do from the inside.

Need to dump the dirt and clean the surface where the crack is.

The crack was probably caused by water freezing in the dirt in the winter time.

Will be a good idea to dump the dirt and turn it upside if left outside in freezing temperatures.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate this comment.

Answer (score 0):

I'd remove the dirt, clean the surface really well, let it dry thoroughly and then mix up some JB Weld epoxy (J-B Weld 8265S Original Cold-Weld Steel Reinforced Epoxy) and poke some into the crack  and along the back of the crack. You can use some rubbing alcohol and a paper towel to wipe out the excess that oozes out the front surface. If you have a large rubberband or something that could embrace the pot and put some compression on it like a tourniquet. Maybe a lot of packing tape or duct tape wrapped well around once or twice over to hold it firm while the epoxy dries. On the inside surface of the pot you can layer up the epoxy and cover it with a strip of thin plastic like from a 2 liter, or even some fiberglass mesh, or repair fabric like for roofing. Then just turn the pot so the crack is to the back out of sight.